# How can i merge items of a Laravel Collection based on keys?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a Laravel Collection with a lot of duplicated items like that:

```
[
  id: 'NAME1',
  prop1: 'yes',
  prop2: null,
  prop3: 'bla',
  prop4: null
],
[
  id: 'NAME1',
  prop1: null,
  prop2: 'yes'
  prop3: null,
  prop4: 'bla'
]
```

And i want to merge the elements with the same 'id' property, and get a collection  like that, preserving both properties:

```
[
  id: 'NAME1',
  prop1: 'yes',
  prop2: 'yes',
  prop3: 'bla',
  prop4: 'bla'
]
```

When i use `$collection->unique('id')` i only get a collection like that, losing the prop2 and prop4 of
the second element:

```
[
  id: 'NAME1',
  prop1: 'yes',
  prop2: null,
  prop3: 'bla',
  prop4: null
]
```

How can i solve it? I doesn't find any method of Laravel Collections which could merge elements of a Collection when one of the elements had a null key.

Comment: I don't think there is a function on collections that solves this problem.  You might need to write your own function.  You could `array_walk` over the collections and compare the arrays.

Comment: So, there is no way to do that without iterating all elements?

Comment: I certainly can't visualize any other way to do it.  You need to walk the first collection and from it build a result-collection, examining the fields to fill in non-NULL values.  And, you'll also have to decide what to do if you encounter more than one non-unique value ... for example, in the OP, if (say) `prop1` of the first record was (say) `"no."`  So, an algorithm of your own devising, suitable to your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a macro that will do what you want:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

Collection::macro('mergeByKey', function ($key) {
    return $this->groupBy($key)->map(function($group) {

        $filteredGroup = collect($group)->map(function($item) {
            return collect($item)->reject(function($value, $key) {
                return $value === null; 
            });
        });

        return array_merge(...$filteredGroup->toArray());
    })->values();
});
```

Then you can use it on a collection like this:

```php
$collection = collect([
    [
        'id' => 'NAME1',
        'prop1' => 'yes',
        'prop2' => null,
        'prop3' => 'bla',
        'prop4' => null
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'NAME1',
        'prop1' => null,
        'prop2' => 'yes',
        'prop3' => null,
        'prop4' => 'bla'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'NAME2',
        'prop1' => null,
        'prop2' => 'fdsa',
        'prop3' => null,
        'prop4' => 'asdf'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'NAME2',
        'prop1' => 'fdsa',
        'prop2' => null,
        'prop3' => 'asdf',
        'prop4' => null
    ],
]);


$result = $collection->mergeByKey('id');
```

Result:

```
Collection {#268 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "id" => "NAME1"
      "prop1" => "yes"
      "prop3" => "bla"
      "prop2" => "yes"
      "prop4" => "bla"
    ]
    1 => array:5 [▼
      "id" => "NAME2"
      "prop2" => "fdsa"
      "prop4" => "asdf"
      "prop1" => "fdsa"
      "prop3" => "asdf"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to merge all non-null properties for each id (you have only one ID in your list, but I assume there can be many)
1) group by id and get the list of [id => [all property lists for id]]
2) for each id:
2a) remove empty properties from each list
2b) merge all lists into one

It can be done this way with laravel collections:

```
$data = '[
{
"id": "NAME1",
"prop1": "yes",
"prop2": null,
"prop3": "bla",
"prop4": null
},
{
"id": "NAME1",
"prop1": null,
"prop2": "yes",
"prop3": null,
"prop4": "bla"
},
{
"id": "NAME2",
"prop1": "no",
"prop2": "dah",
"prop4": "bla"
}

]
';

      $coll = collect(json_decode($data, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY))
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->map(function ($propGroup) {
          //for each group of 'objects' of property lists
          return $propGroup
            ->map(function ($props) {
              //remove empty properties
              return collect($props)->filter(function ($prop) {
                return !empty($prop);
              });
            })
            ->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
              return $carry->merge($item);
            }, collect());
        });
```